# Make/Create AGU's style bibliographystyle

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing, natbib, harvard-style

I'd like to make/create a bibliography style similar to AGU journals' style, which looks like this:

In the main text:

```
Recent studies have shown similar results [Smith et al. 2001; Christensen et al. 2010].
```

and at the end, in the reference list I want them sorted by first author

```
Christensen D., William J.H. and Smidt J.G.. New Results, New Sci. Journal, E4, 25-49, 2010

Smith J., Robert C. and Harrison F. Old Results, Journal Sci. Tech., 12, 995-999, 2001
```

I have a bib file containing the list of articles e.g.

```
@Article{Smith2001,
 author = {Smith J. and Robert C. and Harrison F},
 title = {Old Results},
 journal = {Journal Sci. Tech.},
 volume = {12},
 pages = "995-999",
 year = "2001"
}
```

Therefore the LaTeX line should be something similar to :

```
Recent studies have shown similar results \citep{Smith2001,Christensen2010}.
```

I tried apalike, plain, unsrt, chicago, harvard and others built-in styles, none of them give me what I want. Either I got something weird in the main text for instance:

```
Recent studies have shown similar results [J ~ et al. 2001; D ~ et al. 2010].
```

or even worth, in the reference list, some styles give me this:

```
  [Christensen2010]  Christensen D., William J.H. and Smidt J.G.. New Results, New Sci. Journal, E4, 25-49, 2010

  [Smith2001] Smith J., Robert C. and Harrison F. Old Results, Journal Sci. Tech., 12, 995-999, 2001
```

I tried to play quite a bit with `makebst` but my experience is too weak for reaching my goals. I also tried to play with the `cite` package options but none of them gives me satisfaction. For those who are interesting in this style, AGU provides a LaTeX [template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/american-geophysical-union) but its usage needs to use `bibitem` which is out of topic here. Furthermore, calling their template implies to get a specific layout which is not what I want here.

Any help would be gracefully appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  it looks like you want the "author-year" option of `natbib`.  the coding of the label information in your `.bib` file may need to be expanded; it would be best to consult the `natbib` manual for details.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. "authoryear" option from natbib is indeed very close to what I want except that reference list is sorted as references are cited but not alphabetically sorted. I'll dig into natbib manual. Thanks again.

Comment: `natbib` has a style `unsrtnat.bst` that presumably would leave your `.bib` file in the same order you created it.  of course, that would mean that you'd have to arrange the entries in the file yourself.

Comment: unsing plainnat.bst works perfectly except for the reference list layout. it shows J. Smith,  Robert C. and Harrison F. Old Results, Journal Sci. Tech., 12, 995-999, 2001 while I'd like to get Smith J., Robert C. and Harrison F. Old Results, Journal Sci. Tech., 12, 995-999, 2001

Comment: try entering authors with a comma between last and first names. i believe that bibtex assumes that this is the convention.  (atart with just a couple, to test.)

Comment: apsr.bst solves my issue. So to summarize: I used \usepackage[authoryear,sort,colon,square]{natbib} with 
\bibliographystyle{apsr} and add a comma after each lastname of the 1st author in my bib database. Thanks Barbara for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the original poster actually solved the problem him/herself, with some help, but we
try not to leave questions unanswered. so here goes.

the appearance of `\citep` in the original question suggested that the author-year
style was wanted.  although some other bib styles support this, the most likely is
`natbib`.  `natbib` has "additional" requirements for its label format, and for those,
it's best to follow a good example; the manual has very good guidance on this, so
the best approach for this is to go to the manual.

the request was for the references to be listed in alphabetical order.  several
approaches were suggested and tried, the one that was finally successful being
`apsr.bst`, launched by `bibliographystyle{apsr}`.  (the two others were (1) `unsrtnat`,
which requires the `.bib` file to be maintained in the intended final order, and
(2) `plainnat`, which does the desired sort, but left the names in a form other than
what was wanted; the form of the names, however, was due to an input misunderstanding -- see below.)

it was requested that names be listed last name first in the bibliography,
but they were showing up instead beginning with the first initial. this could actually
have been predicted from the input shown in the question:

```
 author = {Smith J. and Robert C. and Harrison F},
```

all bibtex processors expect the last and first names to be separated by a comma in
the `.bib` file, so fixing this was easy, if laborious -- insert commas in the names:

```
 author = {Smith, J. and Robert, C. and Harrison, F},
```

thanks to the original poster for reporting what actually worked, so this might help someone else.

Comment: I tried above settings but when citing with `\citep` the citation was expanded (instead of "et al." the full author list was displayed, not what I wanted). I used `\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}` and this fixed the citation.

I am quite new to Latex and I am a bit puzzled as why the bibliography style would change the citation style.

Comment: @metatron -- Most bibliography styles have been defined with input from publishers, so the actual output may vary depending on *which* publisher(s) have made specific requests.  (Publishers have very different ideas about proper presentation.)

Comment: I understand, publishers should guard a uniform layout. But does it make sense that changing a bibliography style changes the citation style? Is it not easier to be able to change them independently? Or am I missing something? In my case I had to change the bibliography style to contract my citation to "et al." but this also changed the layout of my reference list. Isn't \setcitestyle{} designed for this?

Comment: @metatron -- The BibTeX program was written a very long time ago (in the 1980s), and hasn't kept up with developments or techniques.  There is little flexibility by means of options, as expected nowadays; the only practical mechanism for making changes in output presentation is through a `.bst` style, and often the available ones have features "baked in" that aren't exactly what is wanted in particular cases.  The current recommendation is usually "switch to biber or biblatex".